# how to change laravel login from email to username

Tags: laravel, authentication

I have a laravel project which have the login page. It takes email and password and then login. Now I need to change the email form to username but I really can't find the views. can anybody explain me that what should I do? thank you.

Comment: which authentication kit you are using?

Comment: @Behzad I'm not sure cause i'm kinda beginner but you mean breeze or jetstream? if so then it's jetstream

Comment: which laravel version you are using ?

Comment: @AqibJaved 8.12

Comment: I think this tutorial helpful: [How to login with username or email in Laravel authentication](https://devnote.in/how-to-login-with-username-or-email-in-laravel-authentication/)

Answer (score 0):

Your question isn't super clear but if you are looking for where to access the log-in form in your project structure in a standard Laravel project, then you will need to find the views file where the `blade` files are stored. It is usually found in `app/resources/views` but to find it quicker, open up your **IDE**'s search tool (Double shift in jetbrains IDEs) and look for `.blade` to find where your blade files are located. If you find many, you can add more letters to your search like `login.blade`.

Answer (score 0):

// HTML input data

```
<input type="text" name="uid">
<input type="password" name="password">
```

// lets assume the form parameter are store in a var

```
$param = formData();
```

// Here we need to create a associative array to handle request as needed

```
$usernameAttempt    = ['username' => $param['uid'], 'password' => $param['password']];
$emailAttempt       = ['email' => $param['uid'], 'password' => $param['password']];
```

// now we'll try to attempt login using either username or email at once

```
if( Auth::attempt($usernameAttempt) || Auth::attempt($emailAttempt) ){
   // user credentials valid
}  else{
    echo "Username or Password Incorrect!";
}
```